# Strange that Windows 7 is not stopping itself even though I can't find the serial number?

Tags: windows-7

I have some desktop and notebook computers, so I got some Windows 7 Ultimate Edition retail packages and installed on some of them.

On some machine, I entered the serial number right away, and they are fine, but on one machine, I never entered the serial number, and now I can't find the boxes, so I can't enter any serial number but surprisingly, Win 7 just say "Your copy of Win 7 may be pirated or un-licensed...", but it shows a black wallpaper and keep on running!?  Is it supposed to be like that?  It doesn't seem like any slower by the way...

Comment: I havent used Windows 7 , but this used to happen with Windows XP too ,it just gave a message That the installation might be pirtated , but on clicking the icon(or maybe it was a pop up , dont really remember ) it gave you an option to enter a genuine license key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The black screen is normal behavior when a copy of Windows 7 lacks a serial number to activate, but Microsoft won't slow down the computer.  According to [Microsoft's website](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows/help/genuine/faq),

> Until you correct the issue, you'll
>   receive periodic reminders that
>   Windows is not genuine. In addition,
>   to more clearly display these
>   messages, your desktop might turn
>   black. You can reset it, but every 60
>   minutes, it will return to black until
>   the issue is resolved.
>
> Regardless of genuine status, Windows
>   will still be able to get critical
>   security updates. However, access to
>   optional updates or benefits available
>   exclusively to genuine Windows
>   customers, such as Microsoft Security
>   Essentials, might be restricted.

Typically, you will have 30 days to find a serial number that you can activate, or up to 120 days by using the command "slmgr -rearm" in the command prompt [up to three times](http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9136859/Windows_7_will_run_120_days_for_free_Microsoft_confirms).  After that you will be unable to use your computer at all unless you can find a serial number to activate with Microsoft.